# Lost ODBC settings after DB2 client update

Tags: database, db2, odbc

After I updated DB2 Client from V7 to V8. I was surprised to see that all my user/passwords per database in ODBC have been removed. Now, I have no access to my databases and I don't understand how upgrading the DB2 client afects odbc settings. Can anyone explain where users/passwords are stored ? and is there any way to recover them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odbc settings are actually in db2 client in db2cli.ini